# How to remove a legend name in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

***--------------- CODE SNIPPET---------------***

So the code goes like this. There's some code to create a bar chart.

```
# create barChart

barChart= BarChart()
barChartData= Reference(worksheet, min_col=min_col, max_col=max_col, min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row)
barChart.add_data(bar_chart_data, from_rows=True, titles_from_data=True)

barChart.legend.position = 't'
```

...
Then there's some code to create a line chart.

```
# create lineChart
lineChart= LineChart()
lineChartData= Reference(worksheet, min_col=min_col + 1, max_col=max_col, min_row=max_row + 1,
                               max_row=max_row + 1)
lineChart.add_data(compare_chart_data, from_rows=True)
```

...
Then there's some code to add the line chart on top of the bar chart.

```
# combine both charts on top of each other
lineChart.y_axis.crosses = "min"
barChart+= lineChart
```

***---------------END OF SNIPPET---------------***

So what happens is, the chart results into having a legend that says

- Bananas
- Apples
- Oranges
- Series 4

Bananas, Apples and Oranges are the names of the data series of the bar chart. Series 4, is supposed to be the legend for the line chart. I wanna remove it, and I've tried to do below items.

I'm fairly new to python and I have no idea how to remove the legend "Series 4" in the table that's being created by openpyxl.

```
barChart += lineChart
```

I've tried setting below code (after the addition), but it removes everything.

```
barChart.legend = None
```

I've also tried setting below code (before the addition), but it does nothing.

```
lineChart.legend = None
```

Somehow, I feel like it auto - creates the legend name *Series 4* during the addition...

For the sake of testing, I tried to set

```
titles_from_data = True
```

But what this does is just change the legend name to 0%.

I don't want to set it to another value, I just want to get rid of it.

***----- UPDATE -----***

I found a link in the comments section recommended by WBM to try and update the record inside the LegendEntry attribute. It looks something like this.

```
bar_chart.legend.LegendEntry = [(openpyxl.chart.legend.LegendEntry(3, delete=1))]
```

Still to no avail.

For investigation, I tried to print out the contents of the LegendEntry attribute prior to me adding the above code, and after.

Before adding the code, surprisingly, the result is empty.

> *[]*

After I added my code, it looked like something like this.

> Parameters: [idx=3, delete=True, txPr=None]

Despite the LegendEntry being updated, the output still remains the same:

- Bananas
- Apples
- Oranges
- Series 4

Comment: Please include the rest of your code, and ask more general questions specific to your problem e.g. "How to remove a legend name in openpyxl"

Comment: Why don't you set the legend to what you want it to be rather than chartABC.legend = None, e.g. chartABC.legend = ['what','you','want']?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. I updated the post. To answer your second question, I want to be able to set it, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to set it using that way you mentioned it, as bar_chart.legend = ['test', 'test', 'test'], but I came up with this error upon execution: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart.legend.Legend'>

Comment: Thanks WBM, but I tried to enter it that way in your code, and arrived with the same error, plus below. 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Graph'

When I tried to replace them with int values instead of 'Test', the code compiled and executed, but the graph wasn't displayed.

Comment: Check this bugfix https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1017 gives examples how to delete entries in a legend

Comment: Thanks, Man. I checked out the way they tried to remove the legend, and what they've been doing it is they're trying to set the Legend Entry item's delete property to true. Unfortunately, even they weren't able to execute it. I tried it as well. Still no luck. I've tried multiple ways of trying to list what the contents of the bar_chart.legend is, and unfortunately, it's empty. I'll update my question with my findings.

Comment: I agree adding deleted `LegendEntry`s does not seem to work. I generated a file using `openpyxl`, and then opened it, saved it to a new file, and manually removed the legend entry. I then unzipped both files, and compared the chart files - `xl/charts/chart1.xml`. In the code generated file, you can see the `legendEntry` tags - both look the same - so it suggests adding the `delete` entry should work. The one major difference between the two is that the manually generated file tags are namespaced, whereas the code generated ones are not.

Comment: Did you try `openpyxl.chart.legend.LegendEntry(idx=3, delete=True)` on a new line (by itself) before plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using openpyxl 3.0.9.

Looked into the source code for an idea and got this to work:

```
import openpyxl
chart.x_axis = openpyxl.chart.axis.TextAxis(delete=True)
```

Here is more of the code:

```
CHART_ROW = 11
CHART_HEIGHT = 12
DATA_TABLE_START_ROW = 34
LENGTH_DIST_START_COL = 1
SPACER_DIST_START_COL = LENGTH_DIST_START_COL + 10
SPACER_RANGE_START_COL = SPACER_DIST_START_COL + 6
```

.  .  .  .

```
    chart = BarChart()
    chart.style = style  # 1 = black line, 13 = green bold line
    chart.title = "Spacer Distribution Summary"
    chart.height = CHART_HEIGHT  # default is 7.5
    chart.width = 7  # default is 15
    chart.y_axis.title = 'Target Spacer Frequency'
    chart.x_axis = openpyxl.chart.axis.TextAxis(delete=True)

    values = Reference(self.sheet,
                       min_col=SPACER_DIST_START_COL + 1,
                       max_col=SPACER_DIST_START_COL + 1,
                       min_row=self.spacer_distribution_first_row,
                       max_row=self.spacer_distribution_last_row)
    series = Series(values, title_from_data=False)
    chart.series.append(series)
    # chart.legend = None
    pos = f"{column_string(SPACER_DIST_START_COL)}{CHART_ROW}"
    self.sheet.add_chart(chart, pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your error code to the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.legend.html.), we find the usage:

```
openpyxl.chart.legend.Legend(legendEntry=())
```

So you enter in the legendEntry the list you want to update the figure to. I believe in your case this will be

```
chartABC.legend.Legend(legendEntry=(['test', 'test', 'test']))
```

Comment: Thanks WBM, but I tried to enter it that way in my code, and arrived with the same error, plus below. 



**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Graph'**



When I tried to replace them with int values instead of 'Test', the code compiled and executed, but the graph wasn't displayed.